# How to XPATH for Table element which have dynamic Ids

Tags: xpath

I have to get the XPATH for dynamic Ids . The code look like this

```
<table width="100%" role="presentation">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="DWT10" role="presentation">
      <div id="zl__TV-main__rows" class="DwtListView-Rows" style="height: 130px; width: 377px;">
        <div id="zli__TV-main__654" class="RowDouble RowEven " role="treeitem" tabindex="0" aria-label="Unread, hello everyone, Wilkerson, 12:26 AM" aria-posinset="1" aria-level="1">
```

My XPATH goes like this :

```
  //div[starts-with(@id='zl__CLV-main') and ./div [contains(@aria-posinset,'1')]]
```

I am getting:

> Could not evaluate XPATH error.

Comment: You need to have a valid XML in order to make XPATH to work. Is your source file a valid XML? if not, you might want to try regular expressions.

Comment: Also HTML is not parseable using regular expressions. If it is not valid (and this is especially no valid (X)HTML, as it contains nested `<tr/>` tags), you might want to use some HTML parser which outputs clean XHTML. Please post more data, maybe also a link to the site. And tell us _how_ you're calling that XPath expression.

Answer (score -1):

XPAth only works if you have a valid XML source file. In your example there are no closing tags.

Your XPATH is invalid. the `start-with` function must be changed to

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'zl__CLV-main')
```

*comma instead of =*

Comment: XPath works on a DOM. Depending on the parser, it can be HTML or XML. And it doesn't have to be valid. It helps if it is well-formed, but even that is not a requirement with parsers like Nokogiri.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: XPath works on XML, and this might be a DOM representation. Depending on the parser, it can be HTML, XML or DOM. In other words: You can parse HTML as XML without being the result valid in DOM.

Comment: @JensErat Can you give me an example of an XPath implementation that doesn't create a DOM?

Comment: DOM is a valid HTML and well-formed XML. XPath may output anything from an xml to a c# or java source file. For example, I used xpath to generate another xml file which wasn't html.

Comment: There's quite a bunch of them. Have a look at Saxon, which can work in a streaming mode (not constructing a DOM). Most of the XML databases (which implement XPath by offering XQuery) do not use DOM internally. Some parsers will construct a valid DOM from HTML, others won't; just let them parse a table without `<tbody/>` elements (required by "HTML DOM") and check if they get inserted to check. By the way, the XPath specs only mention DOM when something's different. "XPath is a language for addressing parts of an XML document[...]" (from XPath 1.0 specs)